# How can I change pip3 to always install into a certain directory? (I have multiple paths which is confusing things)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pip, homebrew

when i `echo $PATH` i receive `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin`

I feel like this is too long of a path and is confusing things. I seem to have many of the same files / sym links that are unnecessary. I downloaded python 3 via Homebrew but Idle did not work so I downloaded Python 3 from the official site as well which may be confusing things.

I have other modules downloaded in the Cellar via Homebrew.

How can I get Pip3 to always install into the Cellar path? Path being used in PyCharm is /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

bash_profile.txt shows:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

##
# Your previous /Users/me/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/gf/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2017-03-15_at_18:43:29
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-03-15_at_18:43:29: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Which pip3 are you using? (copy the output of `which pip3`). What is the Python interpreter used by the CLI? (`which python3.6`).

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

but in PyCharm and other editors, my path is linked via my Homebrew path:
/usr/local/bin/python

I am still not 100% clear on the whole path thing which I know is extremely important. Can you briefly explain that? I mean if I have python installed at the root of my harddrive basically, should it not detect every module in my computer?
Brew says its bad to leave your python in your user library and installs it in the usr/local/bin. I believe this screws things up.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lh /usr/local/bin/python` and `file /usr/local/bin/python`. I'd like to understand if you have a single python interpreter that is symlinked or two independent. With the limited information, my current best choice would be to remove the official Python 3.6 from your system. Then, depending on whether you'd like the Python 2 or Python 3 version of modules, install them as `python -m pip install ...` or `python3 -m pip install ...` after having verified with `which` that these are the Python interpreters that PyCharm is using.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl The first line output:
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin    34B Mar 16 01:19 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python' 
`where `me` is my username.
The second one output `/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked for Python 3. Anyway, this confirms already that homebrew symlinks from the cellar. `python3.6 -m pip install ...` should install there then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a lot going wrong here. Let's see if we can fix this.

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` is appearing in your `$PATH` *twice*. Open `~/.bash_profile` in a text editor and remove one of them. I'd recommend actually removing the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` at the beginning, because Homebrew has already linked `python3` and `pip3` into `/usr/local/bin` for you, which would be third in your path if you remove those two paths.

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` can also be removed from your `$PATH`; both `python` (2.7) and `pip` (for Python 2.7) are linked in `/usr/bin`, which is the very next thing in your `$PATH`.

As you noted, installing Python 3 from the website as well has confused things. The path that Pycharm is using is correct; that's Homebrew's Python 3.6 folder. The Python 3.6 installation in /Library can be deleted if you want to use Homebrew's only.

If you *really* need IDLE (not sure why you would, since Pycharm is better anyway), you can run `brew linkapps python3` to link the ones from Homebrew's Python 3.6 to `/Applications`.

*Hopefully* that should fix your issues!

Comment: This is getting into unknown territory for me. I do not want to delete the wrong thing. I am also a noob on paths and do not fully understand them as much as I should. I am updating my question with what my bash_profile.txt shows as it will not fit in a comment. Please let me know what exactly to delete. Thanks a bunch @numbermaniac

Comment: @gmonz I'm pretty sure the file needs to be called `.bash_profile` otherwise the terminal won't recognise it. Anyway, here are the lines you need to keep: http://pastebin.com/iWBnifdX. You can delete the rest. As for Python, delete the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/` folder, but don't touch the 2.7 one.

Comment: Okay thanks @numbermaniac.  The file is .bash_profile, sorry. I want to use Python 3.6 though. Why do I keep 2.7? I thought your original answer said 2.7 could be removed? From what I understand I should edit it to http://pastebin.com/tJ2Dhwi3  . Do i need to keep the line referring to my previous macport back up or should I delete that as well. And do I even need macport or is that obsolete? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @gmonz What I said was you can remove the whole Python 2.7 path at the top of your `.bash_profile`, so that it matches the pastebin I linked. What I said by "don't touch the 2.7 one" was to not remove the *actual 2.7 folder* on your system. As for the line referring to your previous macports, that's a note it left there for you, it's not actually executed, so if you don't need it, you can remove it. If you don't use MacPorts at all, you can remove that whole block.

Comment: @gmonz In regards to Python 3.6, you can remove the folder I said in the earlier comment, because you're using the one in Cellar with Pycharm. The one in `/usr/local/Cellar` is Homebrew's one; the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/` folder is the one you installed from the website.

Comment: okay @numbermaniac so just to be clear I should change the file to exactly what you originally pastebinned? Sorry I just dont want to mess anything up. lol sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I have changed it to exactly what you pastebinned. Why should I keep the python 2.7 folder? I am going to delete it. Pip is installing modules into the usr/local/bin.2.7 folder

Comment: I have changed it to exactly what you pastebinned. Why should I keep the python 2.7 folder? I deleted it. Pip is installing modules into the usr/local/bin.2.7 folder. I want to use python 3. So i deleted all and reinstalled with homebrew.
New path: (is this ok?)
`/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/me/.rvm/bin`

It seems to include usr/local/bin twice ...

Comment: For Python 3, you need to use `pip3`, not `pip`. Alright, as long as you're not touching the system python 2.7, you should be ok to delete it then. `/usr/local/bin` being there twice shouldn't be much of a problem; You sure there's not a line in your `.bash_profile` adding that to your path? (Well, you said you changed it to the pastebin, so I assume not then)